# Validity dates for certificates issue with Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've been creating new certificates with `expiry: 43800h`, that's 5 years of validity. However, the "Not Before" and the "Not After" have dates that do not match which the day the certificate was created. It looks calculated using other logic. I don't see an option in the `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` to SET the "not before".

For example, I've created a certificate yesterday (October 18th) and it seems that the "Not Before" "Not After" should be October 18, but it isn't for some reason:

```
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb  8 14:19:00 2023 GMT
        Not After : Feb  7 14:26:00 2028 GMT
```

I wish to have the Not Before/Not After dates match, the day I'm in, that is, the moment were the certificate is created.

NOTE: I'm using the fabric node SDK to create the certificates.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the fabric mailing list member David Enyeart:

> It looks like the dates are bound by the responding Fabric CA’s own
> expiry.
>
> For example if the Fabric CA cert was created in February 2023 and is
> good for 5 years, then in October 2023 you request (enroll) for a
> client certificate with expiry in 5 years, the client cert expiry will
> be February 2028 (since that is when the responding CA is good until),
> not the requested date of October 2028.
>
> Similarly, the start date defaults to the Fabric CA’s start date.
>
> There is a Fabric CA debug message that you’ll get when this happens:
>
> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/main/lib/serverenroll.go#L125
>
> Maybe that should be a log message rather than debug message so that
> administrators would see it.
>
> I think most people set the CA expiries much further out than the
> runtime node and client expiries to avoid such issues.